# После пробуждения компьютера глючит графика

Tags: linux, графика, xubuntu

При пробуждении компа после режима сна, в некоторых приложениях или сайтах графика глючит.

> System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить такую проблему?

P.S На ноутбуке тоже стоит xubuntu и тоже такая проблема.

Comment: Какая видеокарта? Какие драйвера? Что у вас отвечает за гибернацию? Версии Xubuntu и Ubuntu одинаковые? В `journalctl -xe` ничто на видео не ругается?

Comment: Ну это нормальное явление. Просто сверните окно и снова разверните, чтобы обновить графический стек. Если для вас это серьёзная проблема, можете попробовать сменить иксы на wayland, но с ним будет ещё больше проблем.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf свертывание не помогает, только перезапуск приложения

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov знать бы где эту инфу посмотреть